# Мой класс перестал видеть интерфейс import org.slf4j.Logger;

Tags: java, maven

В какой-то момент мой класс перестал видеть интерфейс Logger
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
При этом в зависимостях всё необходимое есть
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Сам починилось откатом ветки на вчерашнее состояние. Затем возврат на текущее состояние не вернул ошибку.